# Ace - Disable line numbers

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying to make a console for a programming language. I want to build this console in HTML. I am currently using Ace-Editor to deal with all the syntax highlighting and keyboard shortcuts etc. However tiny problem remains. The line numbers still appear which isn't iconic for a typical console...

Is there a way to disable the line numbers from appearing in the Ace editor?

e.g.

```
editor.lineNumbers = false
```